# How to Apply Restriction On Password In aspx

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, authentication, passwords

i have a login web page and also a database in SQL. Page is connected with database. problem is that the password in database is in small letters but when i keep caps lock on then i can also login. now i want to restrict that user can add password with number also alphabet. and when password is in small letters and user use caps locks on then password will not match.

This is my Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log_Users]
(
 [Logid] [int] IDENTITY(100,1)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [Username] [varchar](55) NOT NULL,
 [PASSWORD][varchar](55),
 [Time_Logged_in] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [Time_Logged_Out] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Date_Logged_in] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [E_MAIL] [varchar](55) NOT NULL
 )

 insert into dbo.Log_Users
values('Saqib','pakistan',GETDATE(),'02/07/2010',1,GETDATE(),'saqib@wow.com')
insert into dbo.Log_Users
values('Afridi','Oops',GETDATE(),'02/09/2010',1,GETDATE(),'afridi@wowMail.com')
```

And this My aspx code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;


public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USerLogin", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUserName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UPassword", txtPWD.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        int output = (int)cmd.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
        if (output == 1)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username Or Password')</script>");
        }

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username Or Password')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

and the stored procedure is

```
ALTER Proc USerLogin
 (
 @Username VarChar(50), 
 @UPassword varChar(50),
 @OutRes int OUTPUT
 )
 AS
SET @OutRes = 0

IF EXISTS(SELECT top 1 * FROM Log_Users WHERE Username = @Username and PASSWORD = @UPassword)
BEGIN
    SET @OutRes = 1
    Return @outRes 
END
ELSE
    Return @outRes 

GO
```

Can anyone help me where and what code is placed?

Comment: Is it that you always store the password in small letters... ???

Comment: this may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896367/how-to-check-case-sensitive-password-in-sql-server08

Comment: @VidhyaSagarReddy as shown in code i store password pakistan but when i put PAKISTAN it match :(

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your SQL Server collation for your server and database, SQL Server does case insensitive string comparisons. You can use the COLLATE keyword to force it to use case sensitive comparisons.

```
 SELECT 1 WHERE username = 'user' AND (password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) = (@password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```

Where

- CS = Case Sensitive
- AS = Accent Sensitive

See:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx

This is what your Stored procedure would look like:

```
ALTER Proc UserLogin
(
     @Username VarChar(50), 
     @UPassword varChar(50),
     @OutRes int OUTPUT
)
AS

    SET @OutRes = 0

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE username = @Username AND (password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) = (@UPassword COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS))
    BEGIN
        SET @OutRes = 1
    END

    RETURN @OutRes
```

BTW: Have you looked into the [ASP.NET Membership providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? These provide you with a complete implementation to handle users and groups, passwords and password resets.

Question: Do you check for any security on the Details.aspx? Or can I just browse to it? It looks like that judging from your code. Please, Please, Plese have a very good look at the [ASP.NET Forms Authentication features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that have the security features built in by the framework.

Comment: In your 'UserLogin' stored procedure where you do the password comparison.

Comment: Please share the UserLogin stored procedure in that case.

Comment: i post Stored Procedure above